# Firebase hosting rewrites to Cloud Run and Angular app (v13)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I'm using Firebase Hosting to host Angular app (v13). I would like to add rewrites in firebase.json to direct url domain.com/api to my api service on Cloud Run.

This is my rewrites config in firebase.json

```
 "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/api{,/**}",
          "run": {
            "serviceId": "api",
            "region": "europe-central2"
          }
        },
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
```

When I open url e.g. domain.com/api it works ok and loads cloud run. When I open e.g. domain.com/agent it also works ok and angular app loads. However when I open domain.com/api again it doesn't work, cloud run is not loaded but angular app. Everything works again when I clear site data in dev console.

UPDATE!
Thanks @abraham for your comment regarding service worker. I've fixed this problem by adding dataGroups to ngsw-config.json in Angular app:

```
"dataGroups":
  [
    {
      "name": "api",
      "urls": ["/api"],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 0,
        "maxAge": "0u",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a service worker that isn't excluding the API routes from being cached.

Comment: @abraham yes I'm using a service worker. Any hint on how to exclude API routes from being cached?

Comment: Problem fixed, please see my updated question